# Будет ли обособляться или нет "благодаря этому образу"?

Tags: пунктуация, предлоги, деепричастия

Благодаря этому образу сам поэт ответил на повпоо

Comment: Допишите цитату до точки и включая точку.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Обособление не требуется**

Здесь *благодаря* - предлог (по причине, вследствие чего-л.)
*Б. ветерку не так уж и жарко. Спасся б. друзьям. Б. отцу знаю иностранные языки*. ([Большой толковый словарь](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%91%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8F%20&all=x))

Не путать с деепричастием *благодаря*: *Благодаря хозяйку за вкусный обед, мы вышли из-за стола.*